# SynchronizationLockException: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime. - Workaround for TaskCompletionSource in Blazor wasm

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have an asynchronous method which is returning the entered user value of an input form. As long as the user didn't submit the input, the async method `Task<String> Read()` should be waiting. When the user submits the input form the method `Task Execute(EditContext context)` gets triggered. Therefore I used the `TaskCompletionSource` to block the `Read` method as long the form wasn't submit (which works for the wpf app, I did).

```cs
public async Task<String> Read()
{
    StringReadTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    return await StringReadTaskCompletionSource.Task;
}
protected Task Execute(EditContext context)
{
    //...
    StringReadTaskCompletionSource
        .SetResult((context?.Model as ConsoleInput as ConsoleInput).Text);
}
```

But with the above code I get:

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime.
> System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime.
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.Monitor.Monitor_wait(object,int)
> at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait (System.Boolean exitContext, System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Object obj) <0x2e64fc8 + 0x00046> in :0
> at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (System.Object obj, System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Boolean exitContext) <0x2e64ce8 + 0x00022> in :0
> at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (System.Object obj, System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout)

It looks like to be the result of the limitations of razor-wasm, regarding tasks and threads. I tried the workarounds from here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14253#issuecomment-534118256

by using Task.Yield but was unsuccessful. Any idea how to workaround this issue?

[Edit:] I think the main conclusion for me is, that it's not possible with razor-wasm (because of the one thread limitation) to run a synchronous method (`Console.ReadLine()`), and waiting for a user input, without blocking the whole app. It looks like there is no workaround for this. The only way is to replace all this synchronously calls with a new async call like `Console.ReadLineAsync()`.

Comment: Every time I have seen this its where the call is being made.

Comment: Cannot you just use event instead, fire it in Execute and subscribe to it instead of `Read`?

Comment: The ReadLine method gets called, lets say by a third party, and I need to provide the user input. I can create a event when the user enters something, or when ReadLine is fired but then I would still need to wait for the user input.

Comment: This just isn't a wasm compatible solution. I would frown on it in WPF too. You are in an event driven UI, use events.

Comment: Well whoever calls that read should instead subscribe to mentioned event (while read is completely removed in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've inspected code by the github link you provided and noticed that you are doing this:

```
_stringReaderRedirect = new StringReaderRedirect(Read);
```

where `Read` is function mentioned in question. Then inside `StringReaderRedirect` you have:

```
private readonly Func<Task<string>> _ReadRedirectFunc;
public StringReaderRedirect(Func<Task<string>> readredirect) : base("foo")
{
    _ReadRedirectFunc = readredirect;
}
```

And then you do this:

```
public override string ReadLine()
{
    //return _ReadRedirectFunc?.Invoke();
    //return base.ReadLine();
    Task<string> task = _ReadRedirectFunc?.Invoke();

    return task?.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

So you are blocking on asynchronous call, which is the source of exception in question. Doing this is a major no-no in a single threaded environment, like Blazor WASM. If exception you see were not thrown then you would have a deadlock: the only thread (UI) is blocked waiting for the result of `Read`, while `Read` itself depends on user input, for which UI thread is required. There are many similar issues on blazor github repo, [for example](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22400).

The same would happen in WPF by the way, if you did `Read().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` from UI thread. Well not the same, because in case of WPF it would just deadlock, but "will not work" also.

So go async all the way and never block main thread, since it's the only thread you have.

Comment: Thank you, but currently I don't how to design such an api. I need to derivate from StreamReader and StreamWriter which will recieve the forwarded calls from `Console.WriteLine() ` and `string Console.Readline()`. Therefore I can't modify the method signature of Console.Readline. I tried to remove GetAwaiter.GetResult and use instead a loop inside of `Read()`  which checks whether the input field `Command.Text` has a value. But this will also block the thread.

Comment: And what Console.Read\Write even refers to in context of Blazor WASM? Javascript console? But you cannot read from it (in browser).

Comment: It refers to an actual console app which is using System.Console.WriteLine. Please have a look at https://github.com/mfe-/Blazor.Console/blob/master/Demo/ConsoleTest.cs . Printing the text with blazor wasm is no problem, but redirecting the user input from blazor wasm back to System.Console.ReadLine is the tricky part.

Comment: Yes but this cannot work this way. Just replace calls to built-in Console class with your own (or add extension method ReadAsync to built-in console) and you won't lose anything of value. Synchronous reading of user input just not suitable in this scenario.